# Multiple associations on same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have models for a business and for a user. A business may have multiple managers, but only one of those managers can be an owner. I have tried to model as follows:

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :managements
   has_many :managers, through: :managements, source: :user, autosave: true
   has_one :ownership, -> { where owner: true },
                 class_name: 'Management',
                 autosave: true
   has_one :owner, through: :ownership, source: :user, autosave: true
end
class Management < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :business
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :managements
  has_many :businesses, through: :managements
end
```

This all seems to work fine until I try to save the business:

```
business.owner = owner
#<User id: nil, email: "owner@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$04$aXswT85yAiyQ/3Pa2QAMB.4eDs9JPikpFfb8fJtwsUg...", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
business.ownership
#<Management id: nil, user_id: nil, business_id: nil, owner: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
(byebug) business.owner
#<User id: nil, email: "owner@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$04$aXswT85yAiyQ/3Pa2QAMB.4eDs9JPikpFfb8fJtwsUg...", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
(byebug) business.valid?
false
(byebug) business.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9ef5ca5148 @base=#<Business id: nil, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7f9ef2c23e48,'0.101E3',9(27)>, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7f9ef2c23d58,'-0.23E2',9(27)>, address: "line 1, line2, town, county", postcode: "B1 1NL", business_name: "Business 1", deleted_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"ownership.business"=>["must exist"]}, @details={:"ownership.business"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

I don't understand what the `ownership.business` relationship is? What can I do to make this work?

I am using rails 5.0.6.

Comment: Both `business` and `owner` are new records? Try to append `inverse_of: :business` to the `has_one :ownership`

Comment: thank-you, that works. They were both new records perhaps you could explain why it does and why it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append `inverse_of: :business` to the `has_one :ownership`

```
has_one :ownership, -> { where(owner: true) },
                 class_name: 'Management',
                 autosave: true,
                 inverse_of: :business
```

---

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), it seems like the `:inverse_of` option is a method for avoiding SQL queries, not generating them. It's a hint to `ActiveRecord` to use already loaded data instead of fetching it again through a relationship.

I think `:inverse_of` is most useful when you are working with associations that have not yet been persisted.

- Without the `:inverse_of` arguments, `ownership.business` would return nil, because it triggers an sql query and the data isn't stored yet.
- With the `:inverse_of` arguments, the data is retrieved from memory.